# Socket.io get emit event string on server via socket object

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Client:

```
// ... more code 
    .emit('myEventName', {
        // ... more code 
    })
// ... more code
```

Server (socket.io middleware):

```
// ... more code 
io.use(function (socket, next) {
    console.log(socket.??????); // <-- I want to console.log "myEventName"
});
// ... more code
```

How would I in socket.io get a hold of the event name via the socket object? The documentation on `socket.io`'s website is lacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sockets don't keep their event name, the easiest way to do this is to pass the name in your callback.

You can easily check this by console.logging your socket, you won't find this type of field except for the 'callbacks'

[image]

*For instance*